# Minimum length of a ruler that would expand with Hubble expansion

Tags: special-relativity

In a discussion with friends we started wondering how long a hypothetical unbreakable ruler would need to be in order for it to be stretched by the Hubble expansion of the Universe.

Someone claiming to be a trained astronomer vehemently denied that any such ruler could exist. But it seems to me that obviously some sufficiently large length is adequate for this because surely the ruler must stretch if both of its ends cross the cosmic horizon!

To simplify things, we can assume the ruler to be entirely in a void of diameter at least its length so the gravity of other objects can be neglected or by symmetry will even out.

I mentioned that even large objects such as galaxies do not expand with space as they are so-called bound systems (although the astronomer claimed not to be familiar with that phrase and thought I might be making it up!)

However, I argued that for a sufficiently elongated thin object, the acceleration of its own gravity on its ends would probably be fairly insignificant.

This could easily be worked out, and might turn out to be anything but insignificant, although intuitively I would have thought it would again tend to even out over most of the ruler's length.

But assuming its self-gravity over large distances could be neglected, the only thing opposing its expansion would be electromagnetic forces between its atoms tending to counteract the expansion. As the net effect of these would travel at the speed of sound in the metal there must be a length at which the Hubble velocity of the ends relative to each other exceeded this fairly modest speed.

So as the Hubble expansion rate or thingummy (?) is roughly 70 km per sec per megaparsec, if we assume the speed of sound in the ruler steel is 7 km per sec (which seems on the high side, but for the sake of argument) this means that for a ruler longer than a tenth of a megaparsec, which about 330,000 light years, the expansion would outstrip the tensile contraction.

That's how I reasoned, but in a way I hope it is not a complete or even correct answer, because I'd be interested in others' thoughts in relation to this, or a pointer to a definitive answer.

If the idea of measuring length changes of the ruler is problematic, due to needing another ruler for this which would expand equally, let's say the ruler can be said to expand if an observer at one end sees light emitted from the other end become increasingly red-shifted over time.

Comment: +1. This is a GREAT question. If there's no answers I might put a bounty. I looked at your profile and saw you followed a proposal for a Materials Modeling Stack Exchange. If you don't mind another attempt at a Materials proposal, would you be so kind to commit to this? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZTUyZWY5OTQ1NDI4ZGVlMmU5MzM0ZThiZjNhOTRkYWFlMTA1NjM0OWEzOTZhYzlmMTBlNWQ4ZmIzYWE3MWFkN-4At28O9gekwyERVbYPhFIPwyHiajfB5BeMyrZKJaYV0  It started slow but lately it's been booming with 5 commitments/day and very soon it will reach 200.